# Angular Error: No provider for ObservableMedia

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to user ObservableMedia. Application compiles successfully but in browser console i see this error

> ERROR Error: No provider for ObservableMedia!
>       at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
>       at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)

Here is my my code

```
import { Component , OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';    
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import {MediaChange, ObservableMedia} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


constructor(
  public media: ObservableMedia) {

 }

  routeLinkClick() {
    if (!this.media.isActive('gt-xs')) {
      this.sidenav.toggle();
    }
  }
```

Please help. thanks

Comment: Have you imported FlexLayoutModule into your NgModule?

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue.

Answer (score 7):

In flex-layout versions 7.0.0-beta.20 and higher ObservableMedia  was replaced with MediaObserver.

*media-observer: ObservableMedia is now deprecated in anticipation of RxJS v7. The new API is called MediaObserver, and provides the exact same functionality as ObservableMedia, except you cannot directly subscribe to it,*

***Developers should subscribe to MediaObserver's media$ property; in place of subscribing directly to ObservableMedia.*** 
- quoted from https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

After I made that change, it worked with no issues on the latest versions as of today:

> "@angular/core": "^7.1.1",
>   "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.23",
>   "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
>   "rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3"

Comment: as of flex-layout versions 7.0.0-beta.24 and higher `The stream data type for asObservable is now MediaChange[] instead of MediaChange and media$ is deprecated in favor of asObservable().` https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your imports at the top of your app.module.ts file:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

And add this into your imports array within the @NgModule of your app.module.ts file:

```
FlexLayoutModule
```

Answer (score 2):

`ObservableMedia` replaced by [`MediaObserver`](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/MediaObserver) from [@angular/flex-layout v7.0.0-beta.24 (2019-03-17)](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

**Before:**

> import {MediaChange, ObservableMedia} from "@angular/flex-layout";
>   constructor(public media: ObservableMedia) {}

**After:**

```
import {MediaChange, MediaObserver} from "@angular/flex-layout";
constructor(public media: MediaObserver) {}
```